# Rewrite Maps in IIS7 - Not redirecting

Tags: redirect, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to use a separate config file, named "rewritemaps.config", that contains the URLs I want to redirect. The file is in the root directory (same place as the web.config). The format of the Redirects.config file I have is:

```xml
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
        <add key="aspx/drvmain.aspx"
             value="http://www.newdomain.com/folder2/page2.aspx" />
        <add key="aspx/jobs_AboutUs.aspx"
             value="http://www.newdomain.com/folder1/jobs.aspx" />
        <add key="aspx/page.aspx"
             value="http://www.newdomain.com/folder1/page2.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

In my web.config file, I have:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config" />
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect rules">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent"
                            url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

In the IIS Manager (which, yes, I have installed the URL Rewrite module), I've even gone and tested the rule and condition against one of my URLs in the redirects.config file and it says it works. But then when I try going to the URL in my browser, it doesn't redirect as I've specified. In the rewritemaps.config file, I've tried putting the full domain, and I've tried with a "/" before aspx. Nothing seems to work. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I got it working. Was something stupid. In the rewritemaps.config file, I needed "/"s before the key URL. I know I had tried that before, but I must have been missing something somewhere else at the time. Oh well. It works now.

Comment: If it helps you feel any better, I did exactly the same thing myself just last week :)

Comment: It seems that the rewritemaps.config file can be quite heavily cached, so making changes to it isn't always effective.  Ensure that the app pool is recycled (e.g 'touch' web.config) after making changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to determine why this is failing but the best thing you can do is use Failed Request Tracing so that IIS tells you what is happening. With FREB you will get detailed tracing telling you which rules were evaluated and if they matched or they didn't and why not. You can also see the "right" patterns to match and every condition that is evaluated.

See the following link:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Well I did that, and I think it says where it's failing but I still don't know why. It seems to be matching the rule pattern match (that is, "`PATTERN MATCH` says `Matched="true"`. But then the conditions evaluation is failing (`CONDITIONS_EVALUATION_END` is `Succeeded="false"`). As I mentioned, when I take the requested URL and test it in the pattern within IIS, it says that it matches the pattern (basically, "aspx/drvmain.aspx" matches "(.+)" when I test it, but not when it's actually run through a browser).